# Match a variable for a mongodb query only if it exists

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using aggregate to return a list of users that match a certain criteria. The problem is that the variables I get from the front end are not always set.

So I have to do something like this:

```
const match = {};

if (status) {
  match.status = status;
}

if (startDate && endDate) {
  match.createdAt = { $gte: startOfDay(startDate), $lte: endOfDay(endDate) };
}

await User.aggregate([
  {
     $match: match,
  },
]);
```

Is there a way to write this directly inside the query without having to use the `match` variable outside the aggregate?

Comment: Nope, what you're doing is how you do it.

Comment: the only way to do this is to create different api's for every criteria

Comment: Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740760/node-js-aggregate-match-only-if-variable-exists)

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem in a Flask project with MongoEngine by doing some Python logic before creating the pipeline. Since I'm working in Python and it looks like you're working in JavaScript, the solution won't exactly match to what you're doing, but I think the approach is still valid. Every place I use a dictionary you can just use a JSON object.

I have an endpoint that pulls documents matching certain criteria, and I want the user to be able to provide all, some, or none of the parameters: `start_date`, `end_date`, and `location_id`

In may case, the endpoint accepts a GET request with url args added on

`127.0.0.1:5000/expenses?start_date=[some stuff]&end_date=[other stuff]&location_id=[yet more stuff]`

```
@bp.route('/expenses/', methods = ['GET','POST','PATCH'])
@bp.route('/expenses/<sheet_id>', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def expenses(sheet_id = None):
    if request.method == 'GET' and sheet_id is not None:
        return get_expense_sheet(sheet_id)

#####
#   This is the relevant bit 
    elif request.method == 'GET' and sheet_id is None:
        request_args = request.args.to_dict()
        return get_all_expense_sheets(request_args)
#    
#####
    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = request.get_json(force = True)
        return create_new_expense_sheet(post_data)
    elif request.method == 'PATCH':
        patch_data = request.get_json(force = True)
        return edit_expense_sheet(patch_data)
```

When I invoke `request.args.to_dict()` I get something like:

```
{
    'start_date':'12/18/2022',
    'end_date': None,
    'location_id: '639c330e95eccd0cafec2262'
}
```

Then in my `get_all_expense_sheets(request_args)` function I do some additional processing to create `date_dict` and `loc_dict` which will contain information on how the user wants the results filtered.

```
def get_all_expense_sheets(request_args):
    date_dict = {}
    
    # Check if start_date is included, and if so, add it to date_dict
    try:
        if request_args['start_date']:
            date_dict['$gte'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(request_args['start_date'], '%m/%d/%Y')
    except:
        pass

    # Check if end_date is included, and if so, add it to date_dict
    try:
        if request_args['end_date']:
            date_dict['$lte'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(request_args['end_date'], '%m/%d/%Y')
    except:
        pass

    loc_dict = {}

    # Check if location_id is included, and if so, add it to loc_dict
    try:
        if request_args['location_id']:
            loc_dict['$eq'] = request_args['location_id']
    except:
        pass
```

After this block you can start to construct your pipeline based on the existence of `date_dict` and `loc_dict`

The base pipeline without any of this extra logic will look something like this:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        '$match': {
            'startTime': {
                  '$gte': start_date,
                  '$lte': end_date
             },
            'locationId': {
                  '$eq': location_id
             }
        }
    }
]
```

But you can insert `date_dict` and `loc_dict` directly into the pipeline. To do this I used some if logic:

```
if date_dict and loc_dict:
    pipeline = [
        {
            '$match': {
                'startTime': date_dict,
                'locationId': loc_dict
            }
        }
    ]
elif date_dict and not loc_dict:
    pipeline = [
        {
            '$match': {
                'startTime': date_dict
            }
        }
    ]
elif loc_dict and not date_dict:
    pipeline = [
        {
            '$match': {
                'locationId': loc_dict
            }
        }
    ]
else:
    pipeline = [
        {
            '$project': {
                '_id': 1, 
                'startTime': 1, 
                'endTime': 1
            }
        }
    ]
sheets = ExpenseSheet.objects().aggregate(pipeline)
```

Answer (score -2):

you may try something like:

```
    db.User.find(
            { $or: 
               [ { $and: [ { "status": { $exists: true } },{ "status": status } ] }, 
                 { $and: [ { "endDate": { $exists: true } },
                           { "startDate": { $exists: true } }, 
                           { $gte: startOfDay(startDate), $lte: endOfDay(endDate) }] } 
               ] })
```

Comment: This won't work. `$exists` check the existence in the database. I'm trying to find a way to check if the variable exists.

Comment: hi so can you explain in detail which variable you want to check? did you try the find() query provided?

Comment: The OP needs to check whether various request parameters are included, not whether fields exist in the user documents.