# Node.Js Aggregate $match only if variable exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my database I have data of the type:

```
{
        "_id": "xxx",
        "amount": 800,
        "title": "teste",
        "date": "2020-05-13T18:35:20.000Z",
        "paid": true,
        "type": "expense",
        "category": "debts_loans",
        "__v": 0
}
```

I have the following code where I aggregate the data from the mongoDB database.

```
const { initialDate, finalDate, paid = null } = req.query;

  try {
    const transactions = await Transaction.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          date: {
            $gte: new Date(initialDate),
            $lte: new Date(finalDate),
          },
        },
      }, ...
```

In the `$match` aggregation I want to aggregate `paid` only if it exists, otherwise I want to aggregate just by `date`. How can I do that? The url param `paid` is optional (it may be true or does not exist), is that an anti-pattern?

---

---

Comment: *I wan't to aggregate paid only if it exists* - Do you mean by exists in request ?

Comment: yes, exists in the request. In the data base it will always exists as true or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need to switch the query based on `paid` like below :

```
const { initialDate, finalDate, paid } = req.query; // No need to make it null if it's not there in req.

let pipeline = [];

/** An if check prior to forming query */
paid == undefined ? 
    pipeline.push({ $match: { date: { $gte: new Date(initialDate), $lte: new Date(finalDate) } } }) : 
    pipeline.push({ $match: { paid: paid } })

try {
const transactions = await Transaction.aggregate(pipeline)
} catch () {}
```